# While clicking photo in landscape and also press OK button in landscape mode then image is not displaying in image-view in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-camera, image-capture

- While clicking photo in landscap mode and also pressing ok button in landscape mode then image is not diaplaying in image-view in specific SAMSUNG device which have android version 12 or 13.
- Need to display captured image via camera in landscap mode where confirmation also allowed in landscap mode.

Comment: Please share your code